# (rails4)how can i validate an user cannot book a route with overlapping time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i have an user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_secure_password
     attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :cardnumber, :registration
   validates_uniqueness_of :email
   has_many :bookings
   has_many :routes, :through => :bookings
end
```

then a route model :

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :id, :departurecity, :arrivalcity, :departuretime, :arrivaltime, :train_id
   has_many :stops
   belongs_to :train
   has_many :bookings 
   has_many :users, :through => :bookings
end
```

an finally bookink model:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :route_id, :user_id, :dateb, :hourb, :citydeparture, :cityarrival, :id, :tripclass
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :route
```

The question is how can I make a method on booking model which an user cannot book a train route with overlap time on another booked train route by the same user?

Comment: why do you use `attr_accessible` with rails4?

Comment: when the user does the log in it allows him to access the booking attribute and when an administrator does the log can access and modify all attribute of al models(but its first time using rails4) not sure